# Can all minecraft biomes be present in any newly generated xbox 360 map?

Tags: xbox-360, minecraft-legacy-console

Since Minecraft on the Xbox 360 is not unlimited like the PC counterpart, will every level generated have every biome available?

If not, are there any types of biomes that will guaranteed be available no matter what the seed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's entirely luck of the draw. The world seed determines what is generated, just as if it were an infinite world, but then it's cut off at the boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think every Biome can be on one Map on the Xbox 360 Version but there might be some update to make the world bigger Thus more room for building, Exploring, Mining and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it can happen but it's a very low percent chance. If u get lucky enough it could happen - when you play Minecraft anything is possible so all biomes might be present in one world but nobody really knows so lets just wait and see.

Also one time I came so close I found 22 of 23 biomes - I guess that world didn't bring enough luck. so I tried so many times but remember in Minecraft any thing is possible.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Please make sure to use correct spelling and grammar when posting answers. You may press the edit button below your post to do so. Thank you!

Comment: @Drew - it's 'luck' based on the world's 'seed' number. A 'seed' is a number that starts a 'random number generator' or RNG, which is just an algorithm that spits out what *appear* to be random numbers. This is how computers handle 'randomness' - Basically the biomes are generated semi-randomly, if you provide the same seed then it's likely that the biomes will generate in a similar way.